# Newbie--how to hide and show divs using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to show DIV with id "q1" on page load while hiding divs "q2", and "q3. My code is below, after check the yes/no button, would like to show either div "q2" or div "q3" according to the respond.

How would I do this using javascript? thanks a lot.

```
<div id="q1">
<p>1. Do you like red?</p>

<div class="checkArea">
              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q1Yes" name="q1A" value="Yes"/>
              Yes</label><br>

              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q1No" name="q1A" value="No"/>
              No</label>
</div>

<div id="q2">
<p>2. Do you like green?</p>

<div class="checkArea">
              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q2Yes" name="q2A" value="Yes" />
              Yes</label><br>

              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q2No" name="q2A" value="No" />
              No</label>
</div>

<div id="q3">
<p>3. Do you like dessert?</p>

<div class="checkArea">
              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q3Yes" name="q3A" value="Yes" />
              Yes</label><br>

              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q3No" name="q3A" value="No" />
              No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself yet?

Comment: See `Related` section on the right side of this comment ----->

Comment: I tried that on my own and search for solution, but totally not getting it, I guess I'm just not meant to learn javascript. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/4W7JT/

JS:

```
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 
function hideDiv(id) { 
    if (document.getElementById) 
    { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
            document.id.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        }    
        else { // IE 4 
        document.all.id.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        } 
    } 
}

function showDiv(id) { 
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    } 
    else { 
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
            document.id.visibility = 'visible'; 
        } 
        else { // IE 4 
            document.all.id.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        } 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="javascript:hideDiv('q2');hideDiv('q3');">
    <div id="q1">
<p>1. Do you like red?</p>

<div class="checkArea">
              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q1Yes" name="q1A" value="Yes" onchange="javascript:showDiv('q2');hideDiv('q3');"/>
              Yes</label><br>

              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q1No" name="q1A" value="No" onchange="javascript:showDiv('q3');hideDiv('q2');"/>
              No</label>
</div>

<div id="q2">
<p>2. Do you like green?</p>

<div class="checkArea">
              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q2Yes" name="q2A" value="Yes" />
              Yes</label><br>

              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q2No" name="q2A" value="No" />
              No</label>
</div>

<div id="q3">
<p>3. Do you like dessert?</p>

<div class="checkArea">
              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q3Yes" name="q3A" value="Yes" />
              Yes</label><br>

              <label><INPUT type="radio" id="q3No" name="q3A" value="No" />
              No</label>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for helping, this is a good starting point. Will play with this a bit to understand then try to finishing up the rest myself. @_@

Answer (score 3):

Using pure Javascript, first you need to get the element.

```
var element = document.getElementById('q1');
```

Then you need to set the `display` value.

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

To show them again, you can simply set the value to it's previous setting. For example:

```
element.style.display = "block"; // if it was block.
```

This will hide the element. This will hide it from the page, but not delete it from the DOM.

I'm not going to give you the code; makes more sense to teach you the principle and you can work it out for yourself, otherwise no-one really learns anything!

Comment: +1 that should be enough info for OP, they won't learn if they don't try it out themselves first

Comment: agreed, this is valid code to solve the issue but doesn't show how to show divs, making it an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery for those kinds of operations:

http://jquery.com

include the script in your `<head></head>` tag and then

you can start having q2 and q3 hidden by adding this CSS code:

```
#q2, #q3 { display: none }
```

and when you want to  show them using jquery library do:

```
$("#q2").show(); // where q2 is the id of your div
// or
$("#q1").hide(); // to hide the element
```

I strongly recommend to use jquery to do those operations as it's very optimal and easy to learn/use

Comment: this is flagged as a javascript question, recommending jQuery is a wise choice but not a valid answer unless the original question is updated.

Comment: that make sense, thanks for your answer. But I'd like to learn Javascript. :)

Answer (score -1):

Without using jQuery:

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "none";
};
```